# Can I get HTML emails into Slack?

Tags: email, slack

I want to create a slack channel for all the emails I get with receipts, confirmations and other FYI messages.

I'm doing that so those emails are searchable by my whole team.

I'm using Zapier to get email into Slack. I set Zapier to send just the "plain body" of the email into the slack channel.

The trouble is that when the email hits the slack channel, the messages are hard to read. html emails are easier to read.

Is there a way to get Slack to display full html emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, the only way to get full html in Slack is the official *Email* app (by Slack).
It's only available to teams on paid plans, though.

If you're not using a paid account, you might be interested in [MailClark](https://mailclark.ai) (disclosure: I'm a co-founder), which has several advantages over Zapier:

- The text version is cleaner since we're built for Slack – that makes emails easier to read
- We include a link to open the full HTML version in your browser – so the original formatting is just a click away
- MailClark also allows you to send emails / reply from Slack

Comment: any idea if this has changed in the last three years?